# jComboBox Instead of category name add category ID into the database in java netbeans

Tags: java

i am creating a small inventory control system for my final year. instead of add category name add category id in to the database i don't know how add do the task .what i tried so far i attached.

**i load the category in to jComboBox1**

```
 public void LoadCategory()
    {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javapos","root","");
                insert = con1.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM category");
                 ResultSet rs = insert.executeQuery();
                 jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
                 while(rs.next())
                 {
                     jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString(2));
                 }

            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
    }
```

**add the record into the product table.**

```
String productname =txtproduct.getText();
     String productdec =txtdec.getText();
     int categoryid =jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javapos","root","");

    insert = con1.prepareStatement("insert into product (productname,description,category)values(?,?,?)");
     insert.setString(1,productname);
     insert.setString(2,productdec);
     insert.setString(3,categoryid);
     insert.executeUpdate();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sucsessfully Saved");
```

Comment: You need to change `categoryid`'s type to `String` in the line `int categoryid =jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Comment: i have changed sir. but category name only can added into the database set the category  id instead of name add in to database.

Comment: I'm little bit misunderstand. What do you have in `jComboBox1`? Names or ids? And what do you want to record into the database?

Comment: yes sir. i have record in the database. category table consists of id ,catname only. i can loaded catname  in to my jComboBox1 successfully when i add in to the database should add category id instead of catname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess (from your question) your table `category` should contains such columns:

- `id` - int autoincremented (implicit)
- `productname` - ...
- `description` - ...
- `name` - name of a category

Next. You need to create a custom `JComboBox` item's type. For the example:

```
class CategoryItem
{
    int id;
    String name;

    // add other fields if you want...

    CategoryItem(int id, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

When you're loading the records from the table you're creating the `CategoryItem` class objects and append them to `JComboBox`, like this:

```
public void LoadCategory()
{
    //...
    jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        // rs.getInt('id') - id value of the category record
        jComboBox1.addItem( CategoryItem( rs.getInt('id'), rs.getString('name') );
    }
     //...
}
```

When a new record to be inserted into the table the database set and fill its `id` with a new autoincremented value implicitly:

```
Category categoryItem = (CategoryItem)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

insert = con1.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO product (productname, description, name) VALUES (?,?,?)");

insert.setString(1, productname);
insert.setString(2, productdec);
insert.setString(3, categoryItem.name);
```

To get the last record create a query (example for `MySQL`):

```
getLastCategory.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

If you need to update the category's data you get `CategoryItem` object and take its `id`:

```
CategoryItem item = (CategoryItem)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
int id = item.id;

query.prepareStaement("UPDATE category SET productname = ? WHERE id = ?");
query.setString(1, "new product name");
query.setInt(2, id);
```

Comment: Yes. I guess you meant `rs.getInt(1)` instead of `rs.getInt(0)`?

Comment: Oh! and `insert.setInt(3,categoryItem.id);`

Comment: jComboBox1.addItem(CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2))); if i write this line to load category it is not loaded.

Comment: jComboBox1.addItem(CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2))); if i write this line to load category it is not loaded.

Comment: it didn't work sir jComboBox1.addItem(CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2)));

Comment: @MauricePerry no, on insert operation if id-column is autoincremented its new value should be created automatically

Comment: i couldn't load the JComboBox1 sir.jComboBox1.addItem( CategoryItem( rs.getInt('id'), rs.getString('category') ); this line getting error

Comment: @ProgrammerHari  I've changed the answer (replaced the name of the column `category` to `name`, to except conflict with the name of the table. Don't forget fix your real db table `category` respectively). And maked some fixes below. Try it again